# How to get my program name in list of right click menu on any file

Tags: c#, deployment, registry

I have created a File/folder copy utility in C#.net. its working fine. problem is that when i right click on folder than my program's name appear their and its also working fine. but when i right click on any file or group of files and folder. so tell me which and where i need to create a registry key through my program so i can do that.

Comment: You question is a little hard to understand, could you explain it a little clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question, but here are some links that might help:

**Registering File Types:**

[How to associate a file extension to the current executable in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-to-the-current-executable-in-c)

[Filetype association with application (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222561/filetype-association-with-application-c)

**Windows Shell Integration:**

[Windows Shell Integration using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437972/windows-shell-integration-using-net)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dateparser.aspx