# Add Scan with option in right click menu

Tags: c#, right-click, antivirus

I am making AV as my college project and want to add option of SCAN WITH in right click menu.For that i need to add another form specially to be called when user selects that option.How to add another form and make it a exe because I need to give a exe path/command to open on click.Also how to get path of the file/folder on which that click was called.My AV is in C#.

Comment: What is an "AV"? What have you tried so far? In which context menu do you want to add an entry?

Comment: AV-antivirus
I want entry in Right Click menu.When you right-click on any file/folder,there appears an option on Scan with avast/avg/norton..

Comment: So, you want to enhance the explorer?

Comment: Are you wanting to make the entire anti virus software yourself?

Comment: Trying to make just a basic AV.

Answer (score 0):

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437972/windows-shell-integration-using-net) contains information about writing code for Shell Integration in Windows. [This MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96s74eb0(v=vs.80).aspx) gives some information on working with C# command line arguments. So all you need to do is combine the information in those links with some sort of program development (i.e. using WinForms or WPF) and you should be able to complete your task.